# Set state for incremental numbers input

Tags: reactjs

After months without `reactjs` I forgot how to solve this situation. I have a incremental input for numbers:

HTML:

```
  <input
  type="number"
  value={stockQuantity}
  defaultValue="1"
  onChange={() => bookQuantity(stockQuantity)}
  />
```

React

```
const [stockQuantity, setStockQuantity] = useState(1);

const bookQuantity = (e) => {
   setStockQuantity({ ...stockQuantity, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

I just get errors I don't find the solution and I didn't find any previous work were I handle it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define stockQuantity as an object initially:

`const [stockQuantity, setStockQuantity] = useState({books: 1});`

Then you can just setState in onChange event or create a separate function as you have already made.
You don't have to set the value prop

```
<input
 type="number"
 name="books"
 defaultValue="1"
 onChange={(e) => setStockQuantity({...stockQuantity, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event to your onChange handler and also add name to your input:

```
<input
  type="number"
  name="stockQuantity" // will be passed in e.target.name
  value={stockQuantity}
  defaultValue="1"
  onChange={bookQuantity} // the same as onChange={(e) => bookQuantity(e)}
  />
```

Comment: thanks! It looked to me like the solution but it doesn't work I still get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. Absurd that I have other text inputs working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a little linear solution:

```
  const [stockQuantity, setStockQuantity] = useState(1); // just numbers

  const bookQuantity = (e) => {
  setStockQuantity({ ...stockQuantity, [e.target.name]: 
  e.target.value });
  };
```

HTML:

```
<input
type="number"
name="stock"
value={stockQuantity.books}
defaultValue="1"
onChange={bookQuantity}
// if you want you can use a placeholder
/>
```